# How do you format multiline R package messages?

Tags: r, string, format, message

In developing an R package, I would like to use `R`'s `message()` or `warning()` functions to produce output for my package user.

Sometimes these messages can be long. I can do this (text is just trivial example):

```
message("If you got to this point in the code, it means the matrix was empty. Calculation continues but you should consider re-evaluating an earlier step in the process")
```

Great... But for style, I also want my **lines of code to be less than 80 characters**, so they fit nicely in narrow screens, on GitHub, etc. And then I can use an IDE code reflow tool to reformat my message easily if it changes.

So I try this:

```
message("If you got to this point in the code, it means 
the matrix was empty. Calculation continues but you should consider
 re-evaluating an earlier step in the process")
```

This solves my code criteria -- it is less than 80 character lines and can reflow as expected. But that sticks the whitespace right in my message output, which I also don't want:

```
If you got to this point in the code, it means 
the matrix was empty. Calculation continues but you should consider
 re-evaluating an earlier step in the process
```

So I found this handy function called `strwrap()` that seems to solve the problem:

```
message(strwrap("If you got to this point in the code, it means 
the matrix was empty. Calculation continues but you should consider
 re-evaluating an earlier step in the process"))
```

Output:

```
If you got to this point in the code, it means the matrix was empty. 
Calculation continues but you should considerre-evaluating an earlier 
step in the process
```

Looks nice -- but it eliminated the space between "consider" and "re-evaluating" because that space was at a newline.

Another alternative is to break it up into chunks in the code:

```
message("If you got to this point in the code, it means ", 
"the matrix was empty. Calculation continues but you should consider ",
"re-evaluating an earlier step in the process")
```

This makes the output look correct, but the text can no longer easily reflow with IDE, etc, because it's not one string, so this doesn't work for me on the dev side.

So: How can I make a nicely formatted message that lets me write the message easily across lines?

I have written this function:

```
.nicemsg = function(...) {
    message(paste(strwrap(...), collapse="\n"))
}
```

Is there a better way using a built-in so I don't have to include this function in every R package I write?

Comment: does `message(strwrap(..., prefix = " ", initial = ""))` do what you need?

Comment: @Benjamin Yes, thanks. Unfortunately it's not much more concise than my function so I'll still likely need to wrap it...

Comment: @Benjamin since there have not been any other answers, if you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a couple more arguments from `strwrap` makes this possible

```
message(strwrap(..., prefix = " ", initial = ""))
```

You might be able to improve readability by playing with the order of arguments.  I'm not sure if this is better or not.

```
message(strwrap(prefix = " ", initial = "", 
  "If you got to this point in the code, it means 
the matrix was empty. Calculation continues but you should consider
 re-evaluating an earlier step in the process"))
```

Or, if you prefer wrapping it

```
tidymess <- function(..., prefix = " ", initial = ""){
  message(strwrap(..., prefix = prefix, initial = initial))
}
```

Comment: I particularly like the function name `tidymess`. That's also how I would describe my office.

Comment: Using `prefix = "\n"` in `strwrap()` prevents words from being split when wrapping across the screen.

Answer (score -3):

You can force linebreaks by adding `\n` in the string.

```
message("If you got to this point in the code,\nit means the matrix was empty.\nCalculation continues but you should consider re-evaluating\nan earlier step in the process")
# If you got to this point in the code,
# it means the matrix was empty.
# Calculation continues but you should consider re-evaluating
# an earlier step in the process
```

Comment: This neither solves the IDE reflow problem nor the 80-character limit. Please re-read the question.

Comment: Under what conditions do you want the code to reflow?

Comment: uh, under all conditions?  And yes; this still extends too far like in my first example. The point seems unclear: the code needs to wrap at 80 chars. your suggestions are not wrapping the code at 80 chars (allowing the IDE to reflow the code).

Comment: @nsheff Do you want the line breaks to occur at 80 characters or do you want the IDE to reflow the code based on its own width limits?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been clear; I want the *code* to be able to reflow at whatever the IDE says, 80 characters is just an example.  I don't care  about the *output*. This comment, and your answer, address formatting the output to a certain length, which is fine, but that doesn't bother me so much. It's the *code* I need to stay reflowable (at any arbitrary character stop). does that help? Thanks.