# How do you format a multiline R message with linebreaks?

Tags: r, warnings, r-package

Based on this [excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45693010/8400969) and replies, I learned you could use `message(strwrap(<some message>))` to make the messages in the R package you write flow in the IDE nicely. But how do I go a step beyond reflow to a somewhat formatted message?

The accepted answer there suggests

```
message(strwrap(prefix = " ", initial = "", 
  "If you got to this point in the code, it means 
the matrix was empty. Calculation continues but you should consider
 re-evaluating an earlier step in the process"))
```

Which solves the OP's concern about maintaining spaces at newlines. But what if I wanted "Calculation continues" to actually start a new line, perhaps with a hard return between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, adding `initial = "\n"` means new sentences begin on a new line:

```r
message(strwrap(prefix = "\n", initial = "", 
                "If you got to this point in the code, it means 
the matrix was empty. Calculation continues but you should consider
 re-evaluating an earlier step in the process"))
```

outputting:

```r
If you got to this point in the code, it means the matrix was empty.
Calculation continues but you should consider re-evaluating an earlier step in
the process
```

To add a hard return, one option is to add two newlines with "\n\n") in the message string:

```r
message(strwrap(prefix = "\n", initial = "", 
                "If you got to this point in the code, it means 
the matrix was empty.\n\nCalculation continues but you should consider
 re-evaluating an earlier step in the process"))
```

outputting:

```r
If you got to this point in the code, it means the matrix was empty.

Calculation continues but you should consider re-evaluating an earlier step in
the process
```